# Stop taking input when a blank line encounters

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am trying to stop the loop when user gives a blank line, otherwise push name and score to a vector pair. But this code is not working.

**Input format:**

> <name><score>

e.g.:

> Akash 45

My code is below:

```
 int m;
cin>>m;
vector<pair<string,int>>player;
string name;
int score;
while(1)
{      


    cin>>name;
    if(name.empty())
    break;
    cin>>score;
    player.push_back(make_pair(name,score));
}
```

Also , I have tried the following:

1. `if(name.length()==0)`
2. `while(getline(cin,name))`
3. `if (name=="")`

None of them worked.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean *newline* by a *blank line*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator>>` ignores whitespace, and line breaks are treated as whitespace, so `cin>>name` will never return a blank string (baring an input failure).

To accomplish what you are attempting, you need to use `get::getline()` instead to read an entire line at a time. You can then test for blank lines, and can use `std::istringstream` to parse values from each non-blank line, eg:

```
vector<pair<string,int>> player;
string line, name;
int score;
while (getline(cin, line) && !line.empty())
{
    istringstream iss(line);
    if (iss >> name >> score)
        player.push_back(make_pair(name, score));
}
```

Comment: Hi, this code is working fine. Thanks for that.
But there is one more problem, whenever I am trying to take some another input before this vector pair, the program is not taking input for this pair.

Suppose, I want to take input M ( an int) then this pair.
5
ABC 545
CDS 45

like this

Comment: @deba98 it is difficult to see the actual formatting of the input in a comment. Please edit your question with more detail and formatting.

Comment: I have edited the question. Kindly check , I have added one more input m, before taking input of name.
When I am running your solution, after taking input of m, program gets terminated. But if I disable the line, taking input of  m, program is running fine

Comment: @deba98 you edited your question to include `m` in the context of your old code, not in the context of the code I have given you. Also, you did not show the format of the updated input. Is the value for `m` input on its own line, or is it on the same line as the 1st pair? It makes a big difference, as in the latter case you have to [watch out for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/).

Answer (score 3):

```
 `std::cin >>`
```

does not return with empty input. When the user wrote just the "Enter" key, the std::cin still wait.
I made the test, this is working :

```
std::getline(std::cin, name);
if(name.empty())
break;
```

Edit :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>player;
    std::string name;
    int score;
    while (1)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, name);
        if (name.empty())
            break;
        std::cin  >> score;

        player.push_back(make_pair(name, score));

        // clear the std::cin buffer else the next std::getline won't wait next input
        std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        std::cin.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the

```
std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
std::cin.clear();
```

fix the problem of the second std:getLine

Comment: Hi, I have already tried this method. This does not work.
Can you please give me another method?

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't see it works only in the first loop. I'll found you an other method.

Answer (score 0):

There's a small program to demonstrate you how to achieve so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> nameList;

    std::getline(std::cin, name); // statement X
    nameList.push_back(name);

    for (; ;)
        if (name.empty())
            break;
        else {
            std::getline(std::cin, name); // recalling statement X again
            nameList.push_back(name);
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++)
        std::cout << nameList[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

First of all, let the user input something before going inside the loop directly. As soon as the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the loop will be broken when `name.empty()` conditions becomes true and returns true and break statement is executed.

In the other hand, as long as the user will hit the Enter key and keep writing something line-by-line, the loop will be executed.

Notice that I've used a For loop in this case, you could do the same trick with a While loop as shown:

```
while (true)
    if (name.empty())
        break;
    else {
        std::getline(std::cin, name); // recalling statement X again
        nameList.push_back(name);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this method, but the loop stopped before giving the second time input.
Here is my code:
 std::getline(std::cin, name);
    cin>>score;
    player.push_back(make_pair(name,score));
    for(;;)
    {
        
        if(name.empty())
        break;
        else
        {
            std::getline(std::cin, name);
            cin>>score;
            player.push_back(make_pair(name,score));

        }     
    }

Comment: One problem, you're already trying to accept the whole line for just `name` (which accepts whitespaces too), how do you expect accepting `score` in the same line?